# "at" sign (@) in Python type hints (suggested by Pylance / Pyright)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, type-hinting, pylance, pyright

The [July 2022 release](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-visual-studio-code-july-2022-release/) of the Python extension for Visual Studio Code introduced "*Inlay Type Hints*", which automatically suggests return types of functions that don't have an explicit annotation.  To enable it, you can set `"python.analysis.inlayHints.functionReturnTypes": true` to your IDE user settings (Preferences: Open Settings (JSON) command).

While testing this feature, I noticed the following kind of suggestion, inside a class:
[image]

... where the highlighted text in yellow is the return type suggested by the Python extension, which is based on [Pylance](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release), which itself relies on [Pyright](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright).

My question is: what is the `@` sign in this suggestion supposed to mean? Is there a PEP that refers to this kind of type annotations (with `Self@...`) or is that way of type hinting specific to `Pyright`, differing from the standard convention? Where can I find more information about it?

I've found a similar Stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71261823/what-does-the-symbol-mean-in-python-type-hinting) but it did not get any answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That `@` indicates that `Self` is a `TypeVar`, and `Self@HereIsMyClassName` refers to the `Self` in the context of the class `HereIsMyClassName` (it could also be a function). This is not valid Python. (Technically, it is valid, as the `@` operator is matrix multiplication, so you are matrix-multiplying `Self` and `HereIsMyClassName`. However, that's not what is meant and really doesn't make any sense.) Don't write this in  your code, but know that this is how Pylance shows you `TypeVar`s when it shows you type definitions. (Possibly other editors and extensions as well.)